# How to add subview (a small image view at its edge) to the segment-1 in a uisement control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, segment, uisegmentedcontrol

In my iPhone app I have used an UI Segment Controller with three segments.
I need to add a subView already created `to the second segment`,

for this I have used follow code

```
[segment addSubview:ImgVw forSegment:1];

[segment addSubview:BlueButton forSegment:3];
```

it prompts a warning

> instance method addSubView for segment not found return type defaults to id

And crashes the app

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISegmentedControl addSubview:forSegment:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a8a7a0'

I need to add different subViews for different segments in UISegment controller at many places

how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not method That allow you to insert UiView at particular segment in my opinion.

But you can set custom image plz have a look to below Code

```
NSArray *arrItem=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1", @"2",@"3",@"4",nil];
    UISegmentedControl *seg=[[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:arrItem];
    seg.frame=CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 200);
    [seg insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SearchTransparent.png"] atIndex:2 animated:YES];
    [seg setWidth:90.0 forSegmentAtIndex:2];
    [self.view addSubview:seg];
```